# ""flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import 'app' "" issue could not be resolved

Tags: python, flask

### Background

I am currently making flask-based application with Python but fatal error shown in the title occurs. I searched around the net and found similar questions but there seems be no way to resolve. So I post this issue here to receive comments and advise.

### What I want to do

I want to be able to launch flask-based program.

### Environment

- Windows10 64bit
- Python v3.10.5 (Installer was downloaded from Python.org/downloads/windows/)
- flask v2.2.2

I edit all code and run program on the same computer.

### Configuration

In the user environmental variables in the environment settings window(Control Panel-> Detail Information-> Detail settings of the system-> System Property-> Environmental Variables),following  variables are registered:

- Variable name = FLASK_APP, Value = app.py
- Variable name = FLASK_DEBUG, Value = 1

### Code

content inside the endpoint '/main' is almost omitted. This is because endpoint 'main' is included inside the endpoint '/'.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import gc
import random
import string
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

username = os.getlogin()

# RANDOM STRING FOR MAKING TEMPORARY DIRECTORY:
baseFolder = ""
while True:
    baseFolder = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=12))
    if not os.path.exists("c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder):
        os.mkdir("c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder)
        os.mkdir("c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder+"\\templates")
        os.mkdir("c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder+"\\static")
        break
    else:
        continue

# CREATE app INSTANCE AND CHANGE PATH CONFIGURATION:
app = Flask(__name__,\
            static_folder="c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder+"\\static",\
            template_folder="c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder+"\\templates")
print("app=",app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    global username
    global baseFolder

    BASE_HTML="""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>File Transfer Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2 style="width:98%;
               background-color:LIGHTBLUE;
               padding-top:10px;
               padding-bottom:10px;
               padding-left:20px;
               margin:0 auto;">File Transfer Program</h2>
            
    <br>
    
    <div style='margin:0 auto;'>
            <div style='width:400px; margin:0 auto;background-color:#f1c93c;'>
            <table>
                <form action='{{ url_for("main") }}' method='POST' style='margin:10px;'>
                    <tr style='height:30px;'>
                        <td style='width:100px;text-align:right;'>username&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style='width:250px;'><input type='text' name='username' size=30 value='"""+username+"""'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:100px;text-align:right;'>password&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style='width:250px;'><input type='password' name='password' size=30></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2 style='text-align:center;'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='file_selection_mode' value='indivisual'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='drive_select' value='C'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='init_path' value='//'>
                            <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    """
        
    # RANDOM STRING FOR FILENAME IS GENERATED TO AVOID CACHING ON THE BROWSER.
    output_filename = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=10))    
    os.chdir("c:\\users\\"+username+"\\documents\\"+baseFolder+"\\templates")
    with open(output_filename+".html",mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as fw:
        fw.write(BASE_HTML)

    # REMOVE ELEMENT TO RELEASE MEMORY IN USE.
    del BASE_HTML
    gc.collect()

    return render_template(output_filename+".html")

@app.route("/main",methods=["GET","POST"])
def main():
    global baseFolder
    username = request.form["username"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    file_selection_mode = request.form["file_selection_mode"]

    return "<h2>Hello</h2>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### Error

This is an output on command prompt.

```
C:\\users\\username\\documents > flask run
app= <Flask 'app'>
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py64-3105\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 897, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
  File "C:\py64-3105\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 308, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "C:\py64-3105\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 228, in locate_app
    raise NoAppException(f"Could not import {module_name!r}.") from None
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import 'app'.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 907-919-858
```

### What I can not understand

When I start the program by typing `flask run`, flask says 'Could not import app'. I suppose this means app instance could not be created. But when you see the respose from the code `print("app=",app)` described just after creating app instance, the output was `app=<Flask 'app'>`, which means, I think, app instance is successfully created. How do I understand these gap ? In addition to this, what is the solution to resolve this error ? So I want to hear comments and advices !! Please help me !!

Thank you for reading my question. I really appreciate all members on StackOverFlow. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: What directory is `app.py` in?

Comment: Sorry for long-long no response.
In this case, app.py is located in 
c:\\users\\username\\documents\\python.source